# Way to save integers in a model, compatible with QStyledItemDelegate?

Tags: c++, sql, qt, qstandarditemmodel

I'm searching for a way to save integers and strings in a model and add new ones/ remove them. Maybe I will use QStyledItemDelegate soon too, so it needs to be a compatible solution.

I have some Integers and Strings in a Qsqltable. Next, I want to add a custom row (should only be added to my model, not to the database). As far as I know, QStandarditemmodel does only support Strings. The final goal is to show the data on a tableview or/and listview.

I tried to solve with QStandarditemmodel and setData() which supports QVariant. But I guess the "data" is only for background information.

Comment: Using QStandarditemmodel::setData you can store a QVariant for any purpose, using as role Qt::UserRole (or Qt::UserRole + an integer, see https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ItemDataRole-enum)

Comment: I know about that, but every time I try to append a QStandarditemmodel with an existing QStandarditem, the data gets lost. Why?

Comment: I think I got it... a QStandarditemmodel is like a multi dimensional QVariant. Every Dimension is saved under a ItemDataRole like tooltip, displayrole etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some years of experience, I got the answer: QStandardItemmodel is the best solution for such a need.
I didn't knew a lot about Roles back then, so I didn't knew about DisplayRole, wich would have solved my problem.